# Database design - Storing Condition rules?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, architecture

**Version1**: I have a "FEE" table

```
FEE
-Id
-VariableAmount
-FixedAmount
-CurrencyCode
```

When a withdraw is performed, money taken out of system to user's bank account etc, a variableamount+fixedamount fee is charged per transactions.

**Version2**: I want to charge when it meets specified conditions with a set of fee rules, Example

```
Charge $0 when < $200 

Charge $3 when >= $200

Charge $x when >= $Y
```

I could hardcode it in my web app and that would work, but I want to be able to change it later on, how would you design it when storing these conditions in the database?

FEE 1.* FEE_RULE?? what do you store in the database?

Comment: When the rules change I'd change my code and redeploy. Is that possible for you?

Comment: @usr it would work for now yes :)

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is a Rules Engine.  SQL Server doesn't have one built in but there is an article on MSDN describing how you could build your own.  It probably seems a bit over-engineered for just one rule, but perhaps your application has other rules too.  [Find out more.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964135%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could always put this business logic in a stored procedure responsible for performing a withdrawal. That way when you want to change the logic you don't have to re-deploy the web app.

Answer (score 0):

My approach, in its simplest form, would be something like below.

```
USE tempdb
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.Transactions') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Transactions

SELECT TOP 500 TxnVal = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000
INTO Transactions
FROM sys.columns

;WITH Fee (Id, VariableAmountFloor, VariableAmountCeiling, VariableAmount, FixedAmount, CurrencyCode) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 0,    200,        0.8,    0.1, 'x'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 201,  300,        0.65,   0.1, 'x'    UNION ALL
    --  NB: have chosen 2147483647 as the ceiling because it is the maximum value of the INT type
    --  You will probably have some sort of float
    SELECT 3, 301,  2147483647, 0.4,    0.1, 'x'
)
SELECT   T.TxnVal
        ,VariableFee    = F.VariableAmount
        ,FixedFee       = F.FixedAmount
        ,TxnPlusCosts   = T.TxnVal + F.VariableAmount + F.FixedAmount
FROM Transactions   T
JOIN Fee            F ON T.TxnVal BETWEEN F.VariableAmountFloor AND F.VariableAmountCeiling
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
GO

--DROP TABLE dbo.FeeInterval
CREATE TABLE dbo.FeeInterval (
    FeeIntervalID INT IDENTITY(1,1),    
        CONSTRAINT PK_FeeInterval PRIMARY KEY (FeeIntervalID),

    StartValue NUMERIC(18,2) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT CK_FeeInterval_StartValue CHECK (StartValue > 0),
    -- If EndValue IS NOT NULL Then the interval is TxValue BETWEEN [StartValue, EndValue]
    -- Else (EndValue IS NULL) Then the interval is TxValue >= StartValue
    -- Also, you should check is this intervals are continuous (using a trigger)
    -- and only the last EndValue IS NULL
    EndValue NUMERIC(18,2) NULL, -- Allow null,
        CONSTRAINT CK_FeeInterval_StartDate_EndDate CHECK (StartValue < EndValue),
    VariableAmount NUMERIC(18,2) NOT NULL, 
    FixedAmount NUMERIC(18,2) NOT NULL
);
-- + CREATE INDEX ...
GO

--DROP TABLE dbo.[Transaction] 
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Transaction] (
    TransactionID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        CONSTRAINT PK_Transaction PRIMARY KEY (TransactionID),
    TransactionDate DATE NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT DF_Transaction_TransactionDate DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    -- You should check (using a trigger) if there is an applicable fee for this TxnValue 
    --      If the last EndValue IS NOT NULL Then TxnValue BETWEEN MIN(StartDate) AND MAX(EndValue) 
    --      Else (the last Endvalue IS NULL Then TxnValue >= MIN(StartDate)
    TxnValue NUMERIC(18,2) NOT NULL
    -- Also, you should store the FeeIntervalID used for every transaction
    -- FeeIntervalID INT NOT NULL 
    -- and (maybe) VariableAmount/FixedAmount/TxnPlusCosts NUMERIC(18,2) NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT dbo.FeeInterval (StartValue, EndValue, VariableAmount, FixedAmount)
SELECT 0.01, 200,       0.8,    0.1    UNION ALL -- 0.01 because data type is NUMERIC(,2)
SELECT 201,  300,       0.65,   0.1    UNION ALL
SELECT 301,  NULL,      0.4,    0.1;
GO

INSERT dbo.[Transaction] (TxnValue)
SELECT 0.01 UNION ALL
SELECT 50 UNION ALL
SELECT 200 UNION ALL
SELECT 250 UNION ALL
SELECT 350 UNION ALL
SELECT -0.01; -- Wrong value
GO

--DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetApplicableFee
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetApplicableFee(@TxnValue NUMERIC(18,2))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT  s.FeeIntervalID, s.VariableAmount, s.FixedAmount, @TxnValue + s.VariableAmount + s.FixedAmount AS TxnPlusCosts
FROM (
    SELECT  i.FeeIntervalID, i.VariableAmount, i.FixedAmount,
            i.StartValue, i.EndValue,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i.StartValue DESC) RowNum
    FROM    dbo.FeeInterval i
) s
WHERE   @TxnValue BETWEEN s.StartValue AND s.EndValue AND s.RowNum > 1
OR      @TxnValue >= s.StartValue AND s.RowNum = 1
GO

SELECT  *,
        CASE WHEN f.FeeIntervalID IS NOT NULL THEN 'TxnValue with applicable fee' ELSE 'Wrong TxnValue' END AS [Description]
FROM    dbo.[Transaction] txn
OUTER APPLY dbo.GetApplicableFee(txn.TxnValue) f
-- or
SELECT  *, 
        (SELECT f.TxnPlusCosts FROM dbo.GetApplicableFee(txn.TxnValue) f) AS TxnPlusCosts
FROM    dbo.[Transaction] txn
```

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use oracle filter expression to implement what you suggested through database without changing the application ...
This tutorial will help you for this purpose
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10821/expressionconcepts.htm